# Angular2 ngOnchanges not showing height change with observable

Tags: angular

I have a div that changes height when I press the "Hide" button.

I have captured this height change with a service (like the [cookbook](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-on-changes)) and I get the value change given through correctly when I press the "Get Height" button.

But I want to see if I can get the height value without pressing the button every time. Which means I am trying to implement a ngOnChanges hook to see when height have changed, and then log the new height to the console when ever it has changed.

But I am getting no response from my ngOnChanges hook, even though I have looked at every question asked on it and have tried to implement it the same.

**My Component**

```
import { Component, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';

import { MissionService } from '../../main2/mission.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-child3',
  templateUrl: './child3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child3.component.css']
})
export class Child3Component {

  private switch1 = false;
  height: number;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscription = missionService.missionHeight$.subscribe(
      missionData => {
        this.height = missionData;
        console.log("constructor height = " + this.height)
      })
   }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
        if (changes['height'].currentValue) {
            console.log("ngOnChanges height = " + this.height);
        }
    }

  heightF() { 
    this.height = document.getElementById('mainDiv').offsetHeight;
    this.missionService.announceHeight(this.height);
    console.log("heightF() height = " + this.height);
  }

  onSwitch1() {
    this.switch1 = !this.switch1;
  }
```

**My HTML**

```
<div id="mainDiv">      
    <button id="hide" (click)="onSwitch1()">Hide</button>
    <button (click)="heightF()">Get Height</button>
    <div *ngIf="switch1" id="childDiv"> 
    </div>    
</div>
```

This is the concole response I get every time I hide/unhide the inside div, and then press "Get Height" button, so I know that my observer is working and changing the height.

```
constructor height = 21
heightF() height = 21
constructor height = 198
heightF() height = 198
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html):

> Respond when Angular (re)sets data-bound input properties. The method
>   receives a SimpleChanges object of current and previous property
>   values.
>
> Called before ngOnInit and whenever one or more data-bound input
>   properties change.

Your height attribute is not a input, you should *@Input()* attribute and your *ngOnChange* method will detect changes of your binding data by input from parent component.

f.e.

**simple-parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'simple-parent',
    template: `
      <simple-child [someInput]="someValue"></simple-child>
    `
})
export class SimpleParentComponent implements OnInit {

    someValue: string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

}
```

**simple-child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'simple-child',
    template: 'simple-child.component.html'
})
export class SimpleChildComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

    @Input() someInput: string;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { }

    ngOnChanges(changes:{[propName: string]: SimpleChange}): any {
      if(changes['someInput'] && this.someInput ) {
        console.log('someInput change detect');
      }
}
```

Comment: So does that mean that you can only use ngOnChanges on data that comes from a parent component? I did put `@Input()` in front of my height property, but it did not make any difference.

Comment: You can ngOnChanges only for data that passing by input. just adding annotations will not help. I edited my answer to show you correct using of ngOnChange with Input

Comment: In the end, I just send the observable data to the parent, and from the parent passed it down to the child which triggered the ngOnChanges the way I had it in my code in the beginning. So due to the fact that you reminded me about the ngOnChanges only working with input, it indirectly answered my question so I marked it correct. Thanks allot.